# Inspecting the build output in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I am using teamcity to build my website on a server.  I have the settings for the build worked out, but I need to inspect the build to see how to construct the match for publishing the artifact.

The build takes place on an agent; how do I inspect the build?  It is too big to publish as an artifact, so I need to select a piece. But I can't select a piece because I can't see the file structure of the build.  The build settings I am using should create a package, but I can't exactly reproduce the commands using visual studio on my local pc, so I can't figure out what the package will look like/where it will be without inspecting the Teamcity build.

Comment: Any way you can publish multiple, smaller, artifacts? There's not enough information in TCs build log to help?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is what I will have to do.  I was just hoping that there was some kind of output folder I could access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a series of special steps that did nothing but ls (or in your case dir) the results directories to get insight into the behavior of what was being built. As far as I can tell this sort of "printf," style debugging is the only real way of debugging build steps.